# PHP Running in some directories but not others

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, web-hosting

I have a few simple html websites with a contact form that sends emails via PHP. They all works great with no issues at all. I am trying to build another website now using the same contact form PHP script. However, when the user submits the form, instead of getting a success message, they get a "internal server error" message. The PHP script is identical (with the exception of the captcha key). The HTML is identical (with the exception of the captcha key) and some css styling.

Below is the HTML:

```
    <form action="scripts/contact.php" method="post" target="resultMsg" style="width:300px; margin:auto;">
        <input class="formInput" type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Name"/>
        <br/><br/>
        <input class="formInput" type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email"/>
        <br/><br/>
        <textarea class="formInput" name="message" id="message" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
        <br/><br/>
        <div style="margin:auto;width:fit-content">
            <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"></div>
        </div>
        <br/><br/>
        <input class="send" type="submit" value="Send"/>
    </form>

    <br /><iframe name="resultMsg" id="resultMsg" scrolling="no" style="border:0; height:30px; width:100%"></iframe>
```

Below is the PHP code in the scripts/contact.php file:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'])){
    $captcha=$_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
}

if(!$captcha){
    echo("<p style='color:white; width:100%; text-align:center;'>Error: Please check the captcha box.</p>");
    exit;
}

$secretKey = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";

$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

$url = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=' . urlencode($secretKey) .  '&response=' . urlencode($captcha);
$response = file_get_contents($url);
$responseKeys = json_decode($response,true);

if($responseKeys["success"]) {

    $myemail  = "myemail@ymail.com";
    $subject = "Contact Form Submission";
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];

    $sendMessage = "CONTACT FORM SUBMISSION

    NAME:
    $name

    EMAIL ADDRESS:
    $email

    MESSAGE:
    $message";

    mail($myemail, $subject, $sendMessage);
    echo("<p style='color:white; width:100%; text-align:center;'>Thank you for your email!</p>");


} else {
    echo("<p style='color:white; width:100%; text-align:center;'>Error: message not sent, please refresh the browser.</p>");
}


exit();
?>
```

I have had issues with this last week, but the hosting company added `AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php56 .php` to the htaccess file and it fixed it. They also added extra htaccess files with this line all over the website directories for some reason. Then I think I may have accidentally deleted or changed some of the htaccess files and now it is not working again. What exactly is needed in which htaccess file for this to work correctly? Any ideas why it doesn't work anymore? Thanks

Comment: seems like your hosting environment has multiple php versions and the .htaccess is pointing to the specific version your script needs. Can you check the server error log files and see what is getting logged there?

Comment: All the handler does is insure that .php files are handled by php.  In this case, it's php 5.6 which went End of Life Jan. 1, 2019.  Seems more likely that something else is wrong with your setup or some other issue of which there could be many that result in an internal server error.  As @pinaki commented, you need to look at logs to see what the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the issue was as simple as incorrect file permissions of the PHP script. Changing the permissions of the script to 644 fixed the problem, no more "internal server error".